# Facebook Php image in text message

Tags: php, facebook, api, post, feed

On my page I want post feeds with an image in the text of message and not like a link/url, is possible add to text message something like **htmltags** or **bbcode**?

```
$msg = "<img src=\"urlimg or facebook\" >\nMy text here";

$args = array(
  'message' =>  $mgs,
);

$myfeed = $facebook->api($pageid . '/feed', 'post', $args);
```

update:

i've found a solution but if i post 2 times in a row they will be groupped in the same box in timeline

```
$args = array(
'message' =>  $msg,
'image' => '@'.$path,
'aid' => $album_id,
'access_token' => $token
);  
$photo = $facebook->api($album_id . '/photos', 'post', $args);
```

exist a setting to stop auto-group that? or there is another way to post it like feed with image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't publish an image in the middle of the text message, Facebook do not allow it.

But you can attach an image to the message, it will appear on the left of the message in this way:

```
$msg = "My text here";
imgUrl = "http://urltotheimage.com/path/image.jpg";

$args = array(
    'message' => $mgs,
    'picture' => $imgUrl
);

$myfeed = $facebook->api($pageid . '/feed', 'post', $args);
```

Comment: The @Bojangles answer is for uploading photos to the albums, not for publishing into the feed. It's not the same.

Answer (score 1):

So I spent 30 seconds searching around the [**PHP Facebook API**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/), which really is what *you* should be doing, and found the following example:

```
<?
  // Remember to copy files from the SDK's src/ directory to a
  // directory in your application on the server, such as php-sdk/
  require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');

  $config = array(
    'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
    'fileUpload' => true,
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();

  $photo = './mypic.png'; // Path to the photo on the local filesystem
  $message = 'Photo upload via the PHP SDK!';
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  <?
    if($user_id) {

      // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
      // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
      try {

        // Upload to a user's profile. The photo will be in the
        // first album in the profile. You can also upload to
        // a specific album by using /ALBUM_ID as the path 
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', array(
                                         'source' => '@' . $photo,
                                         'message' => $message,
                                         )
                                      );
        echo '<pre>Photo ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
                       'scope' => 'photo_upload'
                       )); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   

      echo '<br /><a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">logout</a>';
    } else {

      // No user, print a link for the user to login
      // To upload a photo to a user's wall, we need photo_upload  permission
      // We'll use the current URL as the redirect_uri, so we don't
      // need to specify it here.
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'photo_upload') );
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    }

  ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Take note of the `$config` variable values and the `$facebook->api()` call.